# What does "var" mean in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to understand jsp code in the project that calls a method from main code. I have jsp code like this:

```
<s:iterator value="eventsDisplay" var="event">
    <s:set var="eventExtra" value="%{getEventExtra(#event)}" />
```

This `getEventExtra` is in the main code like this:

```
public Map<String, String> getEventExtra(AbstractEventDisplay eventDisplay) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        ...
        ...
```

I am guessing there is connection between jsp code and main code, but in `getEventExtra` method, where does parameter comes from? I see that in jsp we got `event` and it is passed in, but I don't know what var means. `AbstractEventDisplay` is something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractEventDisplay implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    private Date updateTimestamp;

    private String type;

    private String userName;
    private boolean userDeleted;
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Can anyone explain to me how `event` in jsp (or I am guessing from webpage?) is translated into java object.

Comment: You can get idea of jstl library here  https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/jstl-foreach-tag-example-in-jsp-looping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the set tag. For that tag, the value of var is the name of the variable where you store information.  `<s:set var="eventExtra" value="%{getEventExtra(#event)}" />`means "create a variable named eventExtra and store the result of calling getEventExtra(#event) in it".